# Fail to publish my first Azure App

Tags: azure

I followed the tutorial in http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh690944.aspx to create my first app to be deployed to Azure cloud. however, when I tried to "publish to Azure cloud", it consumes more time with no luck; where that the following message appears:

```
[parallel] ...still uploading (elapsed time: 1585 sec.)...
[parallel] ...still uploading (elapsed time: 1590 sec.)...
[parallel] ...still uploading (elapsed time: 1595 sec.)...

null 
[windowsazurepackage] warning: Failed to upload blob      http://testwa.blob.core.windows.net/eclipsedeploy/apache-tomcat-7.0.42.zip. The deployment might not work correctly in the cloud
```

so, please help me in publishing my first app

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the apache-tomcat-7.0.42.zip file into that same directory and re-run.

Comment: apache-tomcat-7.0.42.zip not exist inside my Azure app. anyway, I take a copy from the source apache-tomcat-7.0.42 and place it inside the deploy folder which exists in the Azure app and will try to run again

Comment: unfourtantly, still the same problem exist after I put the folder of apache-tomcat-7.0.42 inside the deploy folder of my Azure App